# How to find out whether computer is connected to internet?

Tags: python, internet-connection

How to find out whether computer is connected to internet in python?

Answer (score 16):

If you have [python2.6](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) you can set a timeout. Otherwise the connection might block for a long time.

```
try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com", timeout=2)
except urllib2.URLError:
    # There is no connection
```

Comment: +1 for the timeout. As Gamecat said, it could also mean that example.com is down :-)

Comment: @Vinay, that's right. Maybe he should try google.com. If google was down. Then I guess there is no internet ;)

Comment: you can set a timeout in 2.5 as well using import socket; socket.setdefaulttimeout(<time in seconds>);

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
import urllib
file = urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/")
html = file.read()
```

and see if that works, or if it throws an exception. Even if you don't use the exact code, you should get the idea.

Comment: Lol, it only gives a false negative if SO is down ;-). Better check a couple of sites and assume connection if at least one is up.

Comment: It was just an illustration - use any site you want!

Comment: it can also fail if a proxy server is running.

Comment: I think you mean "a proxy server is configured but not running".

Comment: Plenty of tricky failure modes. I know an environment that will popup a dialog box warning you that the connection attempt has been logged, and please enter username+password to connect to stackoverflow.com. That's a system-modal dialog I think.